# Twiter API 1.1 version hashtag access

Tags: node.js, express, twitter-oauth

How can I fetch the API from Twitter for hashtags?

- Using Express JS or direct Twitter link
- I am unable to access the API in POSTMAN which they had given in the documentation https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Answer (score 1):

1. You can follow this link for fetching data from Twitter with hashtags, it was very helpful for me

   https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-multifunctional-twitter-bot-49e941bb3092
2. For accessing twitter API in Postman you need to set the following:

   - In Authorization tab, select OAuth 1.0
   - Enter your consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access token secret
   - Enable “Add params to header” and “Auto add parameters”
   - Send the request